# System clock (based on System.Timers.Timer) freezes (but the rest of the WPF UI responds perfectly)

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, dispatcher

In my *WPF* application I have a system clock, that is used for showing the current time. It is based on `System.Timers.Timer`.

The code is as following:

I have a private member in the class:

```
private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
```

In the constructor of the class:

```
_timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
_timer.AutoReset = false;
_timer.Elapsed += TickClock;
_timer.Start();
```

The elapsed method is as following:

```
private void TickClock(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    UiInvokeIfNecessary.Invoke(() =>
    {
        header_clock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    });
    _timer.Start();
}
```

When `UiInvokeIfNecessary.Invoke` called the code within the *UI Dispather*.

```
public static void Invoke(Action action)
{
    if (Application.Current == null)
    {
        action();
        return;
    }
    if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        action();
    else
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action, DispatcherPriority.Send);
    }
}
```

The `TextBlock` `header_clock` in the UI looks as following:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="header_clock" 
           Height="30" FontSize="21" Text="00:00:00" Margin="5,0,0,0"  />
```

After the system works for a few minutes, a strange thing happens:
The clock freezes (the clock does not move forward).
I would think that the UI thread is busy, but everything in the UI (except for the clock) works perfectly (navigation between screen, button clicks and etc). So it looks like the UI thread is free.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Why do you set the `AutoReset` property to false and why are you calling `Start()` more than once?

Comment: @mm8 This was just one of my tries to solve the problem. The original code is with AutoReset set to true, and the Start() method is invoked only once. The issue in the question still occurs with those settings for the timer.

Answer (score -1):

WPF applications should use a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netframework-4.7.2), not a `System.Timers.Timer`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how and why this might cause the situation I've described in my question? @Peregrine
I've attached the update of the textblock's text to the UI Dispatcher via Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action, DispatcherPriority.Send);

Comment: @DimaK If you use a DispatcherTimer, the click event will occur on the main UI thread, so no need for any Dispatcher.Invoke() calls.

Comment: true, but how will this solve the freeze issue? What is the difference between using DispatcherTimer and using System.Timers.Timer with Dispatcher.Invoke() calls? @Peregrine

Comment: Take a look at what the AutoReset flag does. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2